# In Sublime Text 2 for OS X, how do I remap the keyboard shortcut ctrl-shift-k (delete line) to ctrl-k

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I did it via System Preferences > Keyboard as Text > Delete Line and mapped it to ctrl-k, but it only deletes the current line I'm on from where my blinking cursor is to the end of the line.

```
If this were in Sublime, pressing ctrl-k would delete from here| out.
```

If the blinking cursor is `|` it would delete from there to the end of the line.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to remap the key bindings to delete the current line, or to delete from the cursor to the end of line?

Comment: Delete all the current line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your user key binding file, create the following entry (accessible via `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`). This creates a file by the name of `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` in your User folder.

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/Default/Delete Line.sublime-macro"} }
]
```

Just as a side note, if you find you would like to remap current key bindings, check `Preferences -> Key Bindings - Default`. You can search for the key combination, and see the associated command and arguments. You can then create an entry in your user defined key maps with your chosen key combination, and the same command. Thus remapping to match your own personal preference. This, of course, works beyond just the default package, but for plugin key bindings, you will need to look in the appropriate package folder for the key map commands.

Hope that helps!